How to deal with low values of coupling coefficient in resonant circuits?
Im not a eletrical expert, so bear with me. Im trying to simulate a LC circuit coupled with a RL circuit, sweeping the frequency from 0 to a arbitrary number and observe the system's response when the LC circuit is at its resonancy frequency. When i use the "perfect" coupling coefficient (1), as expected, the voltage in the first circuit increases at the resonancy frequency and decreases as the frequency moves away from resonance, as shown in the image below.

However, when i try to use more realistic values, like 0.1, the result changes completely. There is still have a voltage peak at the resonancy frequency but the voltage doesn't drop significantly as the frequency moves away from resonance. So, how should i handle this in real world and in the simulation? What can i do to work with real-world values and keep the results similar to those with "perfect" coupling? Is it possible?


You can use the realistic coupling k=0.1 and lower the Q by loading the output with a load. To match the Q of the original sweep. By transformer source R by N^2 turns ratio one can estimate the load required with a 1-k factor.  (But I don't think you want that. Let me explain.)
Both sweeps are asymmetric and would ring Right to Left in XY mode or HF to LF.
The right circuit is shown lossless LC and thus has high Q and long settling time once energized. The left side has a series R which damps the response (lossy). The lower k, higher Q also higher Zo with output load R will restore (lower) the Q but also attenuate greatly.
You must define the design spec.
You must also test the sweep according to the bandpass settling time or BW. Asymmetry is a sure sign of sweeping too fast.
Since Qp = R/Xo where Xo is magnitude  L = C at resonance fo
BTW, you cannot sweep faster than the decay time, T of the envelope. If Td = 0.35/BW-3dB and you know BW then you can anticipate the required sweep rate near & after resonance.  High Q from low k, = high impedance parallel means slow sweep.

Simulation
Extend the time on your LTspice sweep e.g. te= 200 ms to 1s

Oh! Thanks! Its very helpful and your explanation is very clear to me, unfornatunaly, i cant upvote your answer because i dont have 15 of reputation

That’s Ok maybe those that can but didn’t know how to answer will or not

@D.A.S. Upvote his question and it should give him enough rep to vote on your answer.
